# webpack gives module.js error

Tags: module, webpack

I use windows and have installed **webpack** already globally. I ran the **webpack** command to build a bundle. When I run the command, I get the error **module.js throw err;**. Please see the image below.

[image]

The content of the **webpack.config.js** is

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './app.js',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to having webpack install as a Global module, you need to add it to your local dev dependencies.

the following should resolve the above mentioned issue.

```
> npm i -D webpack
```